# mac os - "Trust request error (-402,653,181)"

Tags: xcode, itunes, finder

When I connect my iPhone XS to my MacBook (Big Sur 11.1) and open the Finder tab for the iPhone I am asked whether the Computer should trust this phone.
When I click the button "Trust" I get the error:

`"Trust request error (-402,653,181)"`

Answer (score 3):

After updating the devices Mac and iPhone and still getting this error.

Finally I found the issue, my McAfee blocking me.

1. Verify request privilege is enable.
2. run the command  `sudo /usr/local/McAfee/AntiMalware/VSControl stopoas`

Once the McAfee is disabled.
you can sync your iPhone to the Mac/Xcode.

Comment: you can start it back by run 
 sudo /usr/local/McAfee/AntiMalware/VSControl startoas

Comment: Ben, It works fine once I disable McAfee but once I start the OAS service again it gives me same error.